# Windows Phone C# MediaElement or Image resizeing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I need some help with this problem:

I have Page in Portrait view. On top 1/3 field is reserved for MediaElement or Image, 2/3 on bottom: there are Buttons and TextBlocks.

I need to do this:

1. If element tapped (done)
2. brute rotate phone view (done)
3. resize over the entire page width and height MediaElement and Image, without refreshing the source

Thanks, for help

Answer (score 0):

Just give your UI element names and fill the "PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged" method. 
Just like this:

```
<Image x:Name="IndexImage"></Image> //every Image needs an source so this code does not work
```

And the method in c# is like this:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e){
if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
{
    IndexImage.height = 100; //for example
}

else
{
   IndexImage.height = 50; //for example
}
```

And take a look at this: 
[Quickstart Screen orientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)